# Paypal express checkout in Node.js (error 10410)

Tags: node.js, paypal, token, paypal-sandbox

I have been unable to to successfully parse the returned token to authenticate final Paypal sandbox payment process. Any help or input would be greatly appreciated :)

REF:

https://github.com/petersirka/node-paypal-express-checkout
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/integration/

Here is the error I am returned:

```
ACK: 'Failure',
VERSION: '52.0',
BUILD: '22708556'
L_ERRORCODE0: '10410',
L_SHORTMESSAGE0: 'Invalid token',
L_LONGMESSAGE0: 'Invalid token.',
L_SEVERITYCODE0: 'Error'
```

Client side:

```
<form id="myContainer" method="post" action="/api/payment/payone"></form>
    <script>
        window.paypalCheckoutReady = function () {
           paypal.checkout.setup('XXX', {
           environment: 'sandbox',
           container: 'myContainer'
           });
        };
     </script>
     <script src="//www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async></script>
```

API:

```
payone: function(req, res) {
    var paypal = require('paypal-express-checkout').init('username', 'password', 'signature', 'return url', 'cancel url', 'debug');



    paypal.pay('20130001', 10.00, 'XX', 'USD', false, function(err, url) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        res.redirect(url);
    });


    paypal.detail( "token", "PayerID", function(err, data, invoiceNumber, price) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
    });

}
```

Finally, paypal-express doc:

```
var parser = require('url');
var https = require('https');
var qs = require('querystring');

function Paypal(username, password, signature, returnUrl, cancelUrl, debug) {
this.username = "XXX";
this.password = "XXX";
this.solutiontype = 'Mark';
this.signature = "XXX";
this.debug = debug || false;
this.returnUrl = 'XXX';
this.cancelUrl = 'XXX';
this.url = 'https://' + 'api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com' + '/nvp';   //'https://' +        (debug ? 'api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com' : 'api-3t.paypal.com') + '/nvp';
this.redirect = 'https://' + 'www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';      //https://' + (debug ? 'www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' : 'www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
};

Paypal.prototype.params = function() {
var self = this;
return {
    USER: self.username,
    PWD: self.password,
    SIGNATURE: self.signature,
    SOLUTIONTYPE: self.solutiontype,
    VERSION: '52.0'
};
console.log(self);
};


Paypal.prototype.detail = function(token, payer, callback) {

if (token.get !== undefined && typeof(payer) === 'function') {
    callback = payer;
    payer = token.get.PayerID;
    token = token.get.token;
}

console.log(token);
var self = this;
var params = self.params();




params.TOKEN = token;
params.METHOD = 'GetExpressCheckoutDetails';

self.request(self.url, 'POST', params, function(err, data) {



    if (err) {
        callback(err, data);
        return;
    }

    if (typeof(data.CUSTOM) === 'undefined') {
        callback(data, null);
        return;
    }

    console.log('3.3');
    var custom = data.CUSTOM.split('|');
    var params = self.params();

    params.PAYMENTACTION = 'Sale';
    params.PAYERID = payer;
    params.TOKEN = token;
    params.AMT = custom[1];
    params.CURRENCYCODE = custom[2];
    params.METHOD = 'DoExpressCheckoutPayment';


    self.request(self.url, 'POST', params, function(err, data) {

        if (err) {
            callback(err, data);
            return;
        }
        console.log('3.4');
        callback(null, data, custom[0], custom[1]);
    });
});

return self;
};




 Paypal.prototype.request = function(url, method, data, callback) {




var self = this;
var params = qs.stringify(data);

if (method === 'GET')
    url += '?' + params;

var uri = parser.parse(url);
var headers = {};


headers['Content-Type'] = method === 'POST' ? 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' : 'text/plain';
headers['Content-Length'] = params.length;

var location = '';
var options = { protocol: uri.protocol, auth: uri.auth, method: method || 'GET', hostname: uri.hostname, port: uri.port, path: uri.path, agent: false, headers: headers };

var response = function (res) {
    var buffer = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
    })

    req.setTimeout(exports.timeout, function() {
        callback(new Error('timeout'), null);
    });

    res.on('end', function() {

        var error = null;
        var data = '';

        if (res.statusCode > 200) {
            error = new Error(res.statusCode);
            data = buffer;
        } else
            data = qs.parse(buffer);

        callback(error, data);
    });
};

var req = https.request(options, response);

req.on('error', function(err) {
    callback(err, null);
});

if (method === 'POST')
    req.end(params);
else
    req.end();

return self;
};

Paypal.prototype.pay = function(invoiceNumber, amount, description, currency,      requireAddress, callback) {

// Backward compatibility
if (typeof(requireAddress) === 'function') {
    callback = requireAddress;
    requireAddress = false;
}

var self = this;
var params = self.params();


params.PAYMENTACTION = 'Sale';
params.AMT = prepareNumber(amount);
params.RETURNURL = self.returnUrl;
params.CANCELURL = self.cancelUrl;
params.DESC = description;
params.NOSHIPPING = requireAddress ? 0 : 1;
params.ALLOWNOTE = 1;
params.CURRENCYCODE = currency;
params.METHOD = 'SetExpressCheckout';
params.INVNUM = invoiceNumber;
params.CUSTOM = invoiceNumber + '|' + params.AMT + '|' + currency;

self.request(self.url, 'POST', params, function(err, data) {

    if (err) {
        callback(err, null);
        return;
    }

    if (data.ACK === 'Success') {
        callback(null, self.redirect + '?cmd=_express-    checkout&useraction=commit&token=' + data.TOKEN);
        return;
    }

    callback(new Error('ACK ' + data.ACK + ': ' + data.L_LONGMESSAGE0), null);
});

return self;
console.log(self);
 };


 function prepareNumber(num, doubleZero) {
var str = num.toString().replace(',', '.');

var index = str.indexOf('.');
if (index > -1) {
    var len = str.substring(index + 1).length;
    if (len === 1)
        str += '0';
    if (len > 2)
        str = str.substring(0, index + 3);
} else {
    if (doubleZero || true)
        str += '.00';
}
return str;
};

exports.timeout = 10000;
 exports.Paypal = Paypal;

exports.init = function(username, password, signature, returnUrl, cancelUrl,    debug) {
return new Paypal(username, password, signature, returnUrl, cancelUrl, debug);
 };

 exports.create = function(username, password, signature, returnUrl, cancelUrl, debug) {
return exports.init(username, password, signature, returnUrl, cancelUrl,   debug);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually we encounter Error 10410 if there is incorrect token or no token passed.
please make sure that you are passing the right PayPal Express token.

for information on error codes you may refer: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/